# If a & b are primtive nth , mth root of unity then ab is kth root of unity

Tags: complex-analysis

Statement: If a and b are primitive nth and mth roots of unity then ab is a kth root of unity for some interger k.

I prove it as follows- 
a^n=1 and b^m=1 (By defn of primitive root of unity)
Implies ab^(mn)=1 for mn=k and clearly k is the integer.

I want to know, whether my approach is right or not? 
Also, what is the smallest value of k? 
I don't have any clue how to find smallest k?

Please help?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.

In general, if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $mn$ is the smallest such $k$.  (You can deduce this from the structure theorem for finite abelian groups, for example, or even just from the theorem that $|MN|=|M||N|/|M\cap N|$ for subgroups of abelian groups, where $M$ is the powers of $a$ and $N$ is the powers of $b$, and $M\cap N = \{1\}$ since any element has order a divisor of both $m$ and $n$.)  But if $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, they don't uniquely determine the minimal $k$--it will depend on the specific $a$ and $b$.  For example, let $\zeta$ be a primitive $3^{rd}$ root of unity.  Then so is $\zeta^2$.  But $\zeta\cdot\zeta$ is a primitive $3^{rd}$ root of unity whereas $\zeta\cdot\zeta^2$ is a primitive $1^{st}$ root of unity.

Comment: Okay i got your point.